# Pair Correlation with Uniformly Distributed Random Numbers

Tags: matlab, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to reconstruct the following "jiggled" distribution from this article: [American Scientist](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/issue.aspx?id=3349&y=0&no&content=true&page=3&css=print).

The article states that the pair correlation function is defined as follows: "For each distance x, the correlation function counts how many pairs of levels are separated by x, whether or not those levels are nearest neighbors. The pair-correlation function for a random distribution is flat..."

I wrote the following code in Matlab to recreate the middle picture in this: [middle picture](http://www.americanscientist.org/include/popup_fullImage.aspx?key=drHo+n4nz//4qnY/WM9UtNJbv+SBL7G/).

```
function two_point(num)
    close(gcf);
    dx = 0:.01:1;
    count = zeros(1,length(dx));

    x = zeros(1,num);
    for i=1:(num-1)
        x(i+1) = x(i) + rand(); % increase at uniformly distributed random distances
    end

    for i=1:length(dx)
        del = dx(i);
        for j=1:(length(x) - 1)
            for k=(j+1):length(x) % start at j+1 so I don't double count
                dist = abs(x(j) - x(k)); % check all neighbors against one another
                if (dist >= (del - .01) && dist <= (del + .01)) % just using 2 significant digits
                    count(i) = count(i) + 1;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    ind = (count == 0);
    count(ind) = nan; % so I don't plot the distances that don't show up
    scatter(dx, count, 'fill');
end
```

The problem is that every picture I generate has a large upward trend (think y = mx, m > 0), where the higher distances seem more likely. Shouldn't the uniform distribution result in a flat picture, because all distances are equally likely? I'm thinking I have a bug somewhere in my code. Here is the trend that gets generated: (redacted, not enough reputation for more than 2 links). I have also tried the double for loop (1->length(x), 1->length(x)) with the same result.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You should be able to post that link now

Comment: First, your x is a random walk. You might want to remove the `x(i)+`. Second, it seems that dist is tested for membership in intervals of length 0.02, including both endpoints. It should be 0.01 without the upper end. I'd replace `dist >= (del - .01) && dist <= (del + .01)` with `dist >= del && dist < del + .01`.

Comment: Also, for bounded uniform random variable samples, not all distances are equally likely. Assuming, you change your init code to `for i=1:num,x(i)=rand(),end`, distances close to 1 can only occur if the pair's elements, sorted, approximate the pair (0,1). If you leave your samples $x$ as a random walk, larger distances than 1 are probable as well, but still there are boundaries near which the likelihood must approach zero.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, with the increasing random walk. Since I was testing non-adjacent points, two distances of .05 from U[0,1] would result in another count for the .1 level. This is my biggest problem. I will also fix the other things you mentioned and report back. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quoted sentence they never talk about a uniform distribution. In fact the statement is not clear to me (what random distribution?).

However, focusing on your code, you are simulating an increasing process as you are imposing postive increments. So it is no surprise that higher distances are more likely to be found if you consider distances between all the possible pairs. Either you focus on distances between adiacent elements only or you need to change your process if you want to show a flat behaviour of the correlation pair.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the increasing in positive increments. I think that is the reason I was not getting the expected results. As  for which distribution was used, this is also an interesting question. I assumed 'uniform' because he said all distances are equally likely but thanks you and ccorn I realize I misinterpreted what was written. I will fix these and report back.